# Doit-on écrire « sûrement » ou « surement » ?

Tags: orthographe, diacritiques

J'ai pour habitude d'écrire *sûrement* avec un *û* mais j'ai entendu dire que l'on pouvait écrire *surement* sans accent circonflexe sur le *u*.

Est-ce vrai ? Si oui, existe-t-il une règle ? Si non, quelle est la bonne orthographe ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

L'orthographe traditionnelle est « sûrement », les [rectifications orthographiques de 1990](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/sites/academie-francaise.fr/files/rectifications_1990.pdf) (présentées de manière plus accessibles [ici](http://www.orthographe-recommandee.info/)) recommandent « surement ».

La rectification supprime les accents circonflexes sur « i » et « u » sauf pour les terminaisons verbales du passé simple, du subjonctif et dans cinq cas d'ambigüité (*dû*, *mûr* et *sûr*, *jeûne(s)* et les formes de *croitre* qui, sans accent, se confondraient avec celles de *croire*).

Comment: Du coup, quelle orthographe doit-on choisir ? Est-ce que l'ancienne est incorrecte aujourd'hui ?

Comment: Celle que tu veux.

Comment: Cela veut dire que les deux écritures sont correctes ? Si c'est le cas, pourquoi faire des rectifications orthographiques si ce n'est pas pour remplacer l'ancienne orthographe ?

Comment: @Zistoloen La nouvelle orthographe n'a jamais vraiment réussi à supplanter l'orthographe traditionnelle. Comme Un francophone l'a dit, les deux variantes sont correctes, mais un texte doit être cohérent. Un mot orthographié selon les rectifications dans un texte écrit selon l'orthographe traditionnelle sera considéré mal orthographié, et vice-versa.

Comment: @Zistoloen, [Position de l'Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#73_strong-em-rectifications-de-l-orthographe-em-strong).

Comment: @Un francophone: Les nouvelles orthographes sont donc soumises à l'épreuve du temps.

Comment: L'usage ne se décrète pas, on peut juste chercher à l'influencer.

Comment: @Kareen rien n’empêche de trouver certaines réformes plus pertinentes que d'autre, et donc d'écrire un texte en en reprenant seulement une partie, la seule chose injustifiable d'alterner entre une orthographe et l'autre pour un même mot.

Comment: Alterner l’orthographe d’un même mot, à quelques lignes de distance, était une activité à laquelle un parfait inconnu nommé Rabelais se prêtait il y a plusieurs siècles. Aucune justification n’est valable pour l’imiter aujourd’hui: plusieurs siècles de rigidification de l’orthographe ont montré que sa compréhension de la langue était fantaisiste.

Answer (score 1):

L'ancienne forme, toujours utiliser l'ancienne forme, sinon tu passes pour ne pas connaître l'orthographe ;)

Comment: D'un autre côté tu passes pour ne pas connaître l'orthographe réformée :)

Comment: Je suis plutôt d'accord avec @user13162, peu de personnes savent que *surement* est valide (pour ma part je ne le savais pas), donc on risque de penser que tu as fait une faute alors que non.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Ton emploi de "peu de personnes" est très arbitraire.  L'orthographe de 1990 est enseigné depuis plus de 20 ans même si elle n'est recommandée que depuis un an. Depuis 1991 mon traitement de texte et logiciel de courrier sont réglés pour vérifier l'orthographe rectifiée. Et la majorité des gens avec lesquels je travaille sont dans mon cas. Ceux qui ne connaissent pas l'orthographe ne sont certainement pas ceux qui ignorent l'orthographe de 1990, et le conseil donné dans cette réponse est à mon avis très mauvais.

Answer (score 0):

Les deux sont corrects.

Tu peux utiliser ce que tu veux, c'est juste que **surement** c'est à dire *sans accent circonflexe* représente la **nouvelle** orthographe du mot. Mais « surement » et « sûrement » sont tous les deux corrects.

Answer (score 0):

Je ne suis pas un locuteur natif mais j'ai appris le français comme langue étrangère (FLE) et je travaille dans une université. J'ai donc un accès illimité aux ouvrages scientifiques et aux livres du supérieur (concours, classes préparatoires, etc.)

Bien que les ouvrages pour écoliers respectent l'orthographe rectifiée, les ouvrages destinés au niveau qui suit le lycée (supérieur, concours, etc.) ne respectent pas toujours la reforme de 1990. Même les livres de français, voire les livres de sciences comme les maths, la physique. la chimie, etc.

Par ailleurs, même le Certificat Voltaire qui vérifie le niveau d'orthographe est tolérant sur ce sujet comme on peut le voir dans cette réponse de sa foire des questions :

https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/a-la-une/questions-projet-voltaire-reforme-orthographe/

Answer (score -1):

Bien sûr que l'acception de  « sûr » comme « vrai  » est infiniment plus fréquente que celle d'aigre.

Qui est-ce qui écrirait : « Il a répondu surement » = « de manière sure » = « aigrie ».

Conclusion : On peut sûrement écrire cet adverbe des deux façons, avec ou sans accent circonflexe. En lisant le contexte on l'aura surement vite bien compris, de manière non-sure...

Answer (score -2):

Seul "sûrement" est correct. Avec un accent circonflexe.

La règle est simplement la suivante : adjectif sûr(e) => sûrement.

Par ailleurs, l'adjectif "sur(e)" existe en français, mais il n'a rien à voir, il signifie "acide, aigre". Cf. https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sur#Adjectif

Comment: cf les autres réponses.

Comment: @XouDo La logique et la cohérence avant tout.

Comment: Alors, on peut dire : pour des raisons de cohérence, "sûrement" est préférable, mais pas : seul "sûrement" est correct (ce qui est inexact).

Comment: Non, l'incohérence marque ici l'incorrection. Ce n'est pas parce que des gens font une faute que cela devient automatiquement correct. D'autant que dans le cas présent - comme je l'ai mentionné - "sur" existe aussi.

Comment: Non ce n'est pas "des gens font une faute", c'est la réforme de 90, donc oui, surement est correct aussi. En conséquence, "seul sûrement est correct" est faux.

Comment: Non, car il n'est pas possible de "réformer" l'orthographe.